# Azure DevOpsのPipelinesでC++のNuGetパッケージを作成したい

Tags: c++, azure, nuget

### 概要

Azure PipelinesでC++のNuGetパッケージを作ることはできますでしょうか?

### 背景

ローカルでビルド、NuGetへのパッケージングをしているプロジェクトのビルドとパッケージング作業を自動化するためにAzure Pipelinesの使用を検討しています
ローカルでNuGetへのパッケージング作業を行う際には、ビルド済みのlibやdllを1つのフォルダにまとめて、nuspecやtargetsファイルを作成してnugetコマンドの実行をしております

パッケージフォルダの構造の一部抜粋

```
D:.
│  DToolsPackage.1.0.2.nupkg
│  DToolsPackage.nuspec
│  tree.txt
│  
└─build
    └─native
        │  DToolsPackage.props
        │  DToolsPackage.targets
        │  
        ├─include
        │  ├─boost (boostのヘッダファイルが入っています)               
        │  └─DTools (DToolsのヘッダファイルが入っています)
        │          
        └─lib
                DTools.dll
                DTools.lib
                DToolsd.dll
                DToolsd.lib
```

targetsファイル

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets"/>
    <PropertyGroup>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup>
        <!-- プロジェクトファイルの「構成プロパティ」→「C++」に該当します。 -->
        <ClCompile>
            <!-- マクロを「HAS_NUGETDTOOLS」を定義します。 -->
            <PreprocessorDefinitions>HAS_NUGETDTOOLS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
            <!-- 追加のインクルードディレクトリに追加するフォルダーを指定します。 -->
            <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../../build/native/include/;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
        </ClCompile>
        <!-- プロジェクトファイルの「構成プロパティ」→「リンカー」に該当します。 -->
        <Link>
            <!-- 追加のライブラリディレクトリに追加するフォルダーを指定します。 -->
            <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../../build/native/lib/;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
        </Link>

    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <!-- ConfigureとPlatformで場合わけ -->
    <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
        <Link>
            <!-- 追加の依存ライブラリに追加して自動リンク -->
            <AdditionalDependencies>DTools.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
        </Link>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
        <Link>
            <AdditionalDependencies>DToolsd.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
        </Link>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- dllのあるフォルダパスを指定 -->
        <NativeLibs Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../../build/native/lib/*.dll" />
        <None Include="@(NativeLibs)">
            <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
            <!-- 出力フォルダにdllを自動で上書き -->
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

できますよ。昔Python 2.7とか、ICU4CのNuGetパッケージ作ってました。だいぶ前なのですが(まだPipelinesになる前)、ご参考に。

https://github.com/kkamegawa/Python27Dev_NuGet
https://github.com/kkamegawa/ICU4C_Nuget